# Extract image name metadata from a mask in an ImageJ batch (.tiff) using r

Tags: r, tiff, imagej

I am attempting to write a for loop in r that will extract image name metadata from a number of ImageJ batches (saved as .tiff files) each containing 1-10 individual masks. So far my code for achieving this for a single mask within a batch is as follows:

```
library(OpenImageR)
library(ijtiff)

tifflist <- list.files(pattern = ".tiff", recursive = T, full.names = T) #save all .tiff files from working directory to a list
batch <- readImage(tiffs[1], all = T) #read in one batch within the list
pixels <- sum(batch[[1]]) #count black pixels of one mask within the batch
name <- read_tags(tiffs[1], frames = "all")[1] #extract the name of that same mask
```

I've been attempting to use the "ijtiff" package to extract the metadata, and, while I'm able to see a bunch of the other metadata with read_tags(), I have not been successfully able to locate the name. Is there another package that I could use a achieve this? Or another function? I know there is an image name associated with each mask, because they can still be found through ImageJ.

The eventual for loop would scale up something like this:

```
results <- data.frame(nrow = length(tifflist), ncol = 2)
colnames(results) <- c("image name", "pixel count")
for (i in length(tifflist)) {
  batch <- readImage(tifflist[i], all = T)
  for (j in length(batch)) {
    pixels <- sum(batch[[j]])
    name <- NA #edit once solution is found
    results[j, 1] <- pixels
    results[j, 2] <- name
  }
}
```

Any guidance would much be appreciated! I am new to working with ImageJ and .tiff files and have limiting experience scaling up my code into for loops.

Comment: what do you mean by name

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk the file name of the original image that is processed in ImageJ. It also shows in the "Slice" column of the ImageJ output table